# MySQL Query to return total hours for state information

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a mysql table capturing state information for a signal every minute in MySQL table as follows:

```
  ID  | state   | timestamp          |
--------------------------------------
'sig1'| 'red'   | '2017-07-10 15:30:21'
'sig1'| 'green' | '2017-07-10 15:31:26'
'sig1'| 'green' | '2017-07-10 15:32:24'
'sig1'| 'red'   | '2017-07-10 15:33:29'
'sig1'| 'red'   | '2017-07-10 15:34:30'
'sig1'| 'red'   | '2017-07-10 15:35:15'
```

I need to come up with a query where it result should be **the most recent time 'sig1' was in 'red' state for more than 5 minutes consecutively**, the output of the query should be

```
ID | state| duration | start_time | end_time
```

So if you guys can help me with the query, that would be great!
cheers!

Comment: Why the plsql tag?

Comment: @jarlh oops.. my bad, will update it.. thanks for pointing that!

Comment: This is easy to do with `window` functions unfortunately Mysql does not support it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT t.id,t.consecutive,t.state
       ,COUNT(*) consecutive_count
       ,MIN(timestamp) start_time
       ,MAX(timestamp) end_time
       ,TIMEDIFF(MAX(timestamp), MIN(timestamp)) AS diff /* for ckeck*/
FROM (SELECT a.* ,
      @r:= CASE WHEN @g = a.state AND @h=a.id THEN @r ELSE @r + 1 END consecutive,
      @g:= a.state g,
      @h:= a.id h    
      FROM yourtable a
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @g:='', @r:=0, @h:='') t1
      ORDER BY id
      ) t
GROUP BY t.id,t.consecutive,t.state
HAVING (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end_time)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time))/60>5
;
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable (
  id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL ,
  state VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  timestamp datetime
);
INSERT INTO yourtable VALUES ('sig1','red','2017-07-10 15:30:21');
INSERT INTO yourtable VALUES ('sig1','green','2017-07-10 15:31:26');
INSERT INTO yourtable VALUES ('sig1','green','2017-07-10 15:32:24');
INSERT INTO yourtable VALUES ('sig1','red','2017-07-10 15:33:29');
INSERT INTO yourtable VALUES ('sig1','red','2017-07-10 15:34:30');
INSERT INTO yourtable VALUES ('sig1','red','2017-07-10 15:39:15');
INSERT INTO yourtable VALUES ('sig2','red','2017-07-10 15:15:15');
```

Output:

```
 id  consecutive    state   consecutive_count   start_time            end_time  diff
 sig1   3           red          3              10.07.2017 15:33:29 10.07.2017 15:39:15 00:05:46
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,MAXTIME ,MINTIME),ID,state FROM
(
  SELECT ID,state,MIN(timestamp)MINTIME,MAX(timestamp) MAXTIME FROM TABLE GROUP BY ID,state
)Z
```

Try above query.